# MongoDB - Selecting Distinct Records Based on Multiple Fields

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB recording information about sport cards.  Each document has values for the sport, manufacturer, brand and variation (see screengrab below).  There are a number of cards associated with each variation.

[image]

I would like to write a query that provides one record for each combination of sport, manufacturer, brand and variation (ignoring that there are multiple cards for each variation).  So I would end up with something like

```
Football, Upper Deck, Exquisite, Signature patch
Football, Upper Deck, Exquisite, Foursome Signature patch
Football, Upper Deck, some-other-brand, some-other-variation
Football, Topps, some-other-brand, some-other-variation
Baseball, Topps, some-other-brand, some-other-variation
```

I've tried a query such as:

```
db.checklists.aggregate([
    {
       $group:
       {
          _id:0,
          manufacturer: {$addToSet: '$manufacturer'},
          brand: {$addToSet: '$brand'},
          variation: {$addToSet: '$variation'},
    }}
 ]);
```

but it returns an empty array.  Can anyone help?

Adding some images or errors I see when running the aggregation suggested in one of the answers below:

[image: MongoShell in Compass]
[image: Compass UI]

Comment: Group by all the three fields; not on `0`. See [Retrieve Distinct Values](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#retrieve-distinct-values).

Comment: Many thanks :). What is the correct syntax for multiple values? I tried `db.checklists.aggregate( [ { $group : { manufacturer : "$manufacturer”,  brand: “$brand”} } ] )` and `db.checklists.aggregate( [ { $group : { manufacturer : "$manufacturer" },{ brand : "$brand" } } ] )` but both gave syntax errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the aggregate function like below in order to group based on multiple fields

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        manufacturer: "$manufacturer",
        brand: "$brand",
        variation: "$variation"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      manufacturer: "$_id.manufacturer",
      brand: "$_id.brand",
      variation: "$_id.variation"
    }
  }
])
```

Edit

***Regarding Mongo Shell (via Compass) returning empty array***

Based on the screenshots attached in the question, it looks like the collection name is wrong. Replace the `db.collection.aggregate` with `db.checklists.aggregate`. Also by default, the shell in compass connects to the `test` db by default. Please make sure you have selected the correct db before executing the query.

***Regarding Aggregation builder error in Compass***

In the `$group` stage you just need to only add the below section

```js
{
  "_id": {
    "manufacturer": "$manufacturer",
    "brand": "$brand",
    "variation": "$variation"
  }
}
```

And In the `$project` stage

```js
{
  "_id": 0,
  "manufacturer": "$_id.manufacturer",
  "brand": "$_id.brand",
  "variation": "$_id.variation"
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.  When I run this in Mongo Shell (via Compass) I get an empty array.  When I run it via the aggregation builder in Compass I get a message `mongodb field '$group' must be an accumulator object`.  I've added images of these to the original question in case I'm doing anything dumb

Comment: @StuartBrown: I have updated the answer addressing the issues you are facing while executing the query. Please check